# how to run a github runner as root

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to run my github runner as root for self hosted linux servers. Can anyone point me to easy solution that I can implement quickly in following code:

```
name: Test
on: push
jobs:
  Test1:
    runs-on: selfhosted-linux # This should run on this self hosted runner only
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

At this point I cannot ssh into the selfhoste linux but can access it only via code in the workflow folder
and I would like to run the checkout as root rather then non root user.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the environment variable `RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT` before you run `config.sh` to set up the runner.  e.g.

`RUNNER_ALLOW_RUNASROOT=1 ./config.sh --token asdlkjfasdlkj`